# Can I configure CounterClockWise's REPL so that it starts up with source and doc?

Tags: clojure, counterclockwise

I find it weird that CCW doesn't start up with the `(source)` or the `(doc)` functions in the namespace.  It also doesn't have `(e)`.  I can't think of being in a situation where I wouldn't want these in my repl.  Is there a way to have these available to me every time I start the CCW repl without having to type in `(use)` manually?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way, but you should be able to see the doc by hovering your mouse over symbols, or pressing F2 while the cursor is over a symbol.

And you can navigate to the source by Ctrl+clicking on a symbol, or pressing F3 while the cursor is over a symbol.

Finally, in the REPL, there is a button on the top right, which prints the full stack trace, same as (e). There might also be a keybinding for it, not sure.